# combining page queries in GatsbyJS/GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, headless-cms, wp-graphql

How can I combine two page queries in GraphQL? I tried simply just combining the data I need into a single query but it keeps giving me an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pages' of undefined". My thought was that either my query is simply just not done right or not fetching the data correct in my box a div.

```
const IndexPage = (props) => {
  const { indexImage, wpgraphql } = props.data

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Home" />
      <BackgroundImage
        className="masthead"
        fadeIn
        fluid={indexImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
      >
        <div className="black-overlay">
          <div className="content-box">
            <h1>Her skriver jeg en overskrift</h1>
            <h2>This is my sub head</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BackgroundImage>
      <div
        style={{
          margin: `0 auto`,
          maxWidth: 1200,
          padding: `0 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
        }}
      >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box a">
            {wpgraphql.pages.nodes[0].undersideACFgraphql.mainText}
          </div>
          <div class="box b">Her skriver jeg tekst 2 :D</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Link to="/page-2/">Gå til en anden side</Link>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default IndexPage

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    indexImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "bolig-partner-ydelser.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fluid(maxWidth: 1800) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
    wpgraphql {
        pages {
          edges {
            node {
              undersideACFgraphql {
                mainText
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
`;
```

When running my wpgraphql query in GraphiQL it works just fine. Here is the wpgraphql query:

```
query MyQuery {
  wpgraphql {
    pages(where: {id: 91}) {
      nodes {
        undersideACFgraphql {
          mainText
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Returns data:

```
{
  "data": {
    "wpgraphql": {
      "pages": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "undersideACFgraphql": {
              "mainText": "Her kan jeg skrive min tekst til mit lille grid :D:D"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you're getting the error is because you're accessing `wpgraphql` incorrectly - you should be using `props.data.wpgraphql.pages` but you're doing `props.wpgraphql.pages`.

Also, your `GraphQL` query for `wpgraphl` returns an object where `pages.edges` is an array, so you have to grab the first object in that array, if that's what you want, and then access it's `node.undersideACFgraphql.mainText` property.

```js
const IndexPage = (props) => {
  const { indexImage, wpgraphql } = props.data

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO title="Home" />
      <BackgroundImage
        className="masthead"
        fadeIn
        fluid={indexImage.childImageSharp.fluid}
      >
        <div className="black-overlay">
          <div className="content-box">
            <h1>Her skriver jeg en overskrift</h1>
            <h2>This is my sub head</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </BackgroundImage>
      <div
        style={{
          margin: `0 auto`,
          maxWidth: 1200,
          padding: `0 1.0875rem 1.45rem`,
        }}
      >
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="box a">
            {wpgraphql.pages.edges[0].node.undersideACFgraphql.mainText}
          </div>
          <div class="box b">Her skriver jeg tekst 2 :D</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Link to="/page-2/">Gå til en anden side</Link>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: I gave it a try and updated code in question. I might be misunderstanding your answer since now it breaks my whole layout and completely fails to compile.

Comment: @TurboTobias not sure I follow, what do you get when you `console.log(props.data)`?

Comment: console.log(props.data) return an object with indeximage and wpgraphql. Screenshot: https://share.getcloudapp.com/9ZuEnL7r

Comment: I've tried updated code but returns TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. I've updated question with how my code looks now.

Comment: @TurboTobias see the edit, wasn't sure how exactly what you were getting but the screenshot makes it clear.

Comment: That did solve the problem! Thank you so much. I guess I wouldn't be needing the where: filter since it will grap the first object in the array or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @TurboTobias you can certainly use the `filter` but you still will be getting an array so either way, but with just a single object, and you'd have to access it by using an index.